# How can I load an assembly without having to know the version?

Tags: c#, gac

I would like to load an assembly from the GAC, but I don't know its version. I do know the `AssemblyName` and `PublicKeyToken`.

```
string dllname="gacname"; //Name os assembly  
AssemblyName name = new AssemblyName(string.Format("{0}, PublicKeyToken=dd3cb1c9aae9ec97" ,dllname));
var x = Assembly.Load(name);
```

This code throws an exception:

> Could not load file or assembly ...

The `dllname` is correct, because it works fine when I specify the version in the `AssemblyName`.

Is it possible to do this without knowing the version?

Comment: @igor - If you are asking for a way to load the assembly without having to know the version, then please state that more clearly in the question. Your question says "..., but I don't know its version"; to me that implies you are indirectly asking for help of how to find that version.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried looking at the contents of the GAC? You can do so by initiating the following command:

```
gacutil -l
```

This should tell you the version of your assembly.

Please read the MSDN documentation for [How to: View the Contents of the Global Assembly Cache](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9x295t9k.aspx)

Comment: I don't think this is what @igor is asking as this doesn't help load an assembly without knowing it's version.

Comment: The way the question is stated is that he does not know the version, thus I was telling him how to find the version. If @igor does not want to know the version, then he should probably state that in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Though it's deprecated, have you tried `Assembly.LoadWithPartialName(dllname);` ?

Comment: Yes i tried and worked, but i can not use deprecated methods